# Elastic Search - display all distinct values of an array

Tags: elasticsearch, facet

For a field mapped as string I have stored list of strings in the ES index, for ex:

```
  subject: ["Scientific Research", "Numerical Analysis", "History of Art"]
```

I would like to query this field and retrieve the full names of categories with their frequency count. What I tried so far with facets:

```
  "query":{
       "match_all": {}
   }, 
   "facets":{
       "tag":{
           "terms":{
               "field":"subject"}
             }
   }
```

is not working as expected because it splits my subject fields into tokens and returns me the top most frequent stopwords. How can I get full entries ordered by counts for an analyzed field, and not only the top 10, if possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `multi-field` define your mapping like so -

```
{
   .....
        ....
            .....
            "subject": {
                "type": "multi_field",
                "store": "yes",
                "fields": {
                    "analyzed": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "standard"
                    },
                    "notanalyzed": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    }
                }
            }
```

Then I would carry out your faceting on the `notanalyzed` field like so -

```
"query":{
      "match_all": {}
  }, 
  "facets":{
      "tag":{
          "terms":{
              "field":"subject.notanalyzed",
              "size": 50
            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: Did this work out for you @Crista23? I'm facing the same issue and the provided solution didn't work for me.

Comment: This is absolutely the correct answer.  You are getting results like this
 Scientific 1
 Research 1
 Numerical 1
 Analysis 1...
The reason is those are the tokens, because the default analyzer(standard) splits on whitespace.  Since you want the full field value, you need to not have it split at all.  This is simply done by not analyzing the data at all.