# Elastic Search Distinct values

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to know how it's possible to get distinct value of a field in elastic search. I read an article here shows how to do that with facets, but I read facets are deprecated:
http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Getting-Distinct-Values-td3830953.html
Is there any other way to do that? if not is it possible to tell me how to do that? it's abit hard to understand solutions like this: [Elastic Search - display all distinct values of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23040782/elastic-search-display-all-distinct-values-of-an-array)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use aggregations:

```
GET /my_index/my_type/_search?search_type=count
{
  "aggs": {
    "my_fields": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name",
        "size": 1000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply buddy. would you please tell me a way of learning these queries step by step? ElasticSearch.org is like a dictionary which you should know exactly what are you looking for.

Comment: Read [this](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index.html) book. Top to bottom. It contains some very good information in it and, most importantly, explanations on how ES works.

Comment: This can be very costly for high-cardinality fields. See the cardinality metric if you're ok with 98-100% accuracy and low memory impact.

Comment: thanks, i tried this but it gives me all of the records

Answer (score 1):

### You can use the `Cardinality` metric

Although the counts returned aren't guaranteed to be 100% accurate, they almost always are for low cardinality terms and the precision is configurable via the `precision_threshold` param.

http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/cardinality.html